# python - os.open(): no such device or address?

Tags: python

I want to try my hands on named pipes so I downloaded a piece of code and modified it to test out:

```
fifoname = '/home/foo/pipefifo'                       # must open same name

def child( ):
    pipeout = os.open(fifoname, os.O_NONBLOCK|os.O_WRONLY)  
    # open fifo pipe file as fd
    zzz = 0
    while 1:
        time.sleep(zzz)
        os.write(pipeout, 'Spam %03d\n' % zzz)
        zzz = (zzz+1) % 5

def parent( ):
    pipein = open(fifoname, 'r')                 # open fifo as stdio object
    while 1:
        line = pipein.readline( )[:-1]            # blocks until data sent
        print 'Parent %d got "%s" at %s' % (os.getpid(), line, time.time( ))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if not os.path.exists(fifoname):
        os.mkfifo(fifoname)                       # create a named pipe file
    if len(sys.argv) == 1:
        parent( )                                 # run as parent if no args
    else:
          child()
```

I tried running the script, it returns this error:

```
pipeout = os.open(fifoname, os.O_NONBLOCK|os.O_WRONLY)     # open fifo pipe file as fd
OSError: [Errno 6] No such device or address: '/home/carrier24sg/pipefifo'
```

What is causing this error? (am running python 2.6.5 in linux)

Comment: Does the pipe actually get created?

Comment: @Thomas, yes the pipe is created.

Answer (score 13):

From `man 7 fifo`:

> A process can open a FIFO in non-blocking mode.  In this case, opening for read only will succeed even if no-one has opened on the write side yet, opening for write only will fail with `ENXIO` (no such device or address) unless the other end has already been opened.

So you're getting this confusing error message because you tried to open a named pipe for reading yet, and you're trying to open it for writing with a non-blocking `open(2)`.

In your specific example, if you run `child()` before `parent()` then this error would occur.

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me on linux:

```
import time
import os, sys
fifoname = '/tmp/pipefifo'  # must open same name

def child( ):
    pipeout = os.open(fifoname, os.O_NONBLOCK|os.O_WRONLY)     # open fifo pipe file as fd
    zzz = 0
    while 1:
        time.sleep(zzz)
        os.write(pipeout, 'Spam %03d\n' % zzz)
        zzz = (zzz+1) % 5

def parent( ):
   pipein = open(fifoname, 'r')   # open fifo as stdio object
   while 1:
     line = pipein.readline( )[:-1]    # blocks until data sent
     print 'Parent %d got "%s" at %s' % (os.getpid(), line, time.time( ))

if __name__ == '__main__':
   if not os.path.exists(fifoname):
     os.mkfifo(fifoname)                       # create a named pipe file
   if len(sys.argv) == 1:
       parent( )                                 # run as parent if no args
   else:
       child()
```

I think the problem is platform dependant, on which platform are you ? o maybe some permissions problem.

Comment: im using ubuntu. I changed permission to 777 but still the same issue. I find it strange that the error says "device or address" and not "file or directory"

Comment: Maybe you are createing the pipe in a remote filesystem or in a file system that does not support pipes.

Answer (score -2):

Linux does not like os commands, such as,

```
os.getlogin()
os.open()
```

and much more.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).